# TF command-line tool: Add files to directory

Tags: shell, tfs

I want to syncronize my solution with outer directory.

I have 3 steps but new files and deleted files are problems:

1. Check out All files :
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" checkout c:\projeler\UnipaCode /recursive
2. Sycronize files with another folder
   "C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.1\SyncToyCmd.exe" -R
3. Check in all files

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"  checkin  /comment:"test" /noprompt

Comment: What have you tried?  This is pretty clearly documented and your question shows very little effort on your part.

Comment: Please be more clear about "outer directory".

Answer (score 3):

[`tf add <file>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9yw4ea0.aspx)

Current folder must be mapped as a TFS workspace for the current user. Then [`tf checkin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z.aspx) to do the add.

**Update for Question Edit**

You can detect what is added and removed by comparing what TFS knows about (`tf dir`) with what is in your local filesystem. There is nothing inbuilt to determine this (no `tf magically-workout-changes` command) and apply `tf add` and `tf delete`.

Remember to allow for files that should not be added to TFS (eg. build intermediate files).

But, it would be far better to have have another workspace mapped to the "another folder" you are synchronising with and work directly with TFS from the source.

Comment: I have to add recursivly I dont know names of files.

Comment: You can use wildcards and there is a recursion option. Please read the docs. Based on the updated question: you'll need to checkout for edit (`tf edit`) files that might be modified, detect added/deleted files (you 'll need to write the change logic) before checking in. None of this is terribly hard.